# proj.4 definition for Moscow GCS_Bessel_1841 to WGS84 convertion

Tags: arcgis-server, coordinate-system, leaflet

I'm developing an app which should show a map using Leaflet framework but i have no luck as 
the coordinate system on the map server differs from the one used by Leaflet.

1. As a map server i use Arcgis which is accessed by means of REST interface
2. The coordinate system used by the server is GCS_Bessel_1841. WKT definition: `GEOGCS["GCS_Bessel_1841",DATUM["D_Bessel_1841",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",37.5],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",55.66666666666666],UNIT["Meter",1.0]`
3. I use proj.4 to convert GCS_Bessel_1841 to WGS84 (used by leaflet) but can't figure out how to make a correct definition especially how to write +towgs84.

The question is how to figure out the values for DX,DY,DZ,RX,RY,RZ.

The afterall my proj.4 defitiion looks like:
+proj=tmerc +lon_0=37.5 +lat_0=55.66666666666666 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +a=6377397.155 +b=6356078.962818188 +pm=greenwich +k_0=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +units=m +no_defs

The Leaflet code:

`var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:3857',
    '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=55.66666666666666 +lon_0=37.5 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs',
    {
        origin: [-5622500.0, 3830200.0],
        resolutions: [
            305.74811314055756,
            152.87405657041106,
            76.43702828507324,
            38.21851414253662,
            19.10925707126831,
            9.554628535634155,
            4.77731426794937,
            2.388657133974685,
            1.1943285668550503,
            0.5971642835598172,
            0.29858214164761665,
            0.14929107082380833
        ]
    });

var map = new L.Map('map', {
    crs: crs
});

var tileUrl = 'http://egip.mka.mos.ru/arcgis/rest/services/osnova_wgs_cached/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
    attrib = '© 2012',
    tilelayer = new L.TileLayer(tileUrl, {
        maxZoom: 12,
        minZoom: 0,
        continuousWorld: true,
        attribution: attrib,
    });

map.addLayer(tilelayer);
map.setView([ 55.750984, 37.617571], 0);

map.on('mousemove', onMapMouseMove);'
`

Comment: Please double-check the WKT definition. I guess it should start with PROJCS["...

Comment: Yes, it does. But how can that help me to make a correct to towgs84? The full WKT: 'PROJCS["Moscow_bessel",GEOGCS["GCS_Bessel_1841",DATUM["D_Bessel_1841",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",37.5],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",55.66666666666666],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]'

Comment: You could save the full WKT as a file, say Moscow_bessel.prj and run gdalsrsinfo, which will return the PROJ.4 notation (among other info):
`gdalsrsinfo Moscow_bessel.prj`

`PROJ.4 : '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +to_meter=0 +no_defs '`

Comment: Please ignore the above comment. Something went wrong when copying & pasting.

Comment: gdalsrsinfo returns for the given WKT:

`PROJ.4 : '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=55.66666666666666 +lon_0=37.5 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs '`

Comment: My Internet search on the given PROJ.4 definition returned 1 hit with `+towgs84=396,165,557.7,-0.05,0.04,0.01,0`. You could give it a try.

Comment: i use now the provided PROJ.4 def., but still have wrong values for tile reference in my request generated by leaflet. i pasted the code to the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is how QGIS writes the proj-string and WKT with +towgs84-parameter:

```
+proj=longlat +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +no_defs

GEOGCS["DHDN",DATUM["Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz",SPHEROID["Bessel 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7004"]],TOWGS84[598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6314"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4314"]]
```

But keep in mind that there is no overall value for converting any Bessel-1841-Data to WGS84.

For Germany, there were a lot of parametres published, until a NADgrid for the whole country was created. This applies the correct shift for every point inside Germany.

Other surveying authorities have done similar conversions, but with other values.

---

**EDIT**

There is a forum entry in Russian http://gis-lab.info/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9386

giving the following proj parameters:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=55.6666666667 +lon_0=37.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k_0=1. +a=6377397 +rf=299.15 +towgs84=396,165,557.7,-0.05,0.04,0.01,0 +no_defs
```

Maybe you get lucky with those values.

Comment: The initial question mentions the projection parameter ["Central_Meridian",37.5], which isn't very far away from Moscow. Using towgs84 parameter values from Germany will not make much sense out there.

Comment: I know that, I just wanted to point out how the towgs84 parametre can be given in WKT.